# Keyboard+Mouse don't work, stuck on login screen

Tags: keyboard, login, mouse, input-devices

I built a system from leftover parts and installed ubuntu on it months ago. I'm pretty sure it's 20.04 as I wanted the latest LTS version. Booting it up now gets me to the login screen as normal, but my keyboard and mouse don't do anything.

The keyboard doesn't have the lights to show that numlock or capslock is on, but the mouse has the LED light up. Neither seem to registering any input and I've tried getting into the bios a couple of times but it didn't work. I tested these peripherals on my gaming system and they worked fine.

Is this a ubuntu issue? I'm aware is a potential issue with the hardware in that system but I was hoping to get some info before resorting to buying new hardware.

Comment: Can you go tty by pressing Ctrl+Alt+f5 If not can you boot into recovery mode ?

Comment: Very basic thing to check - do try the peripherals   in a different USB port (ie front if currently in the back or vice versa) - eg just in case there’s a problem with the connection from the socket on the motherboard to the usb socket (maybe just power going to the ports?).

Comment: It does sound like a hardware issue - if you can’t even enter the bios setup (assuming you’re pressing the right key!), as that should be independent of the installed os.

Comment: What type of keyboard/mouse? Logitech? USB or something else? How are they connected to the computer?